# How to return resultset with Plpython3 in Postgres

Tags: python, postgresql, postgresql-9.2, plpython

How can a plpython function return result set as a normal sql query resultset (not as text).

Here is function definition -

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS demo_report();
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION demo_report()
    RETURNS SETOF <what-type>
AS $$
    rv = plpy.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
    return rv
$$ LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

When I execute **select demo_report();**  it should return the resultset to client rather than text.Right now I am getting this as text - 
[image]

I am using Postgres 9.2 with plpython3u on Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the way to get desired result - 
For Table :

```
CREATE TABLE public.test
(
   id serial NOT NULL,
   name   varchar(200) NOT NULL CHECK (name <> ''),
   salary int,
   created  date,
   CONSTRAINT id PRIMARY KEY (id),
) 
WITH (
  OIDS = FALSE,
  autovacuum_enabled = true
);
```

My Plpython3u function is -

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION demo_report()
  RETURNS SETOF test
AS $$
  resp = []
  rv = plpy.execute("SELECT * FROM test")
  for i in rv:
    resp.append(i)
  return resp

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpython3u' VOLATILE;
```

And I query it like -

```
select * from demo_report();
```

Now I am getting the desired response - 
[image]

Its been quite nice journey with plpython till now. Enjoying it.

Comment: Basically I am returning the type as table name. This works if i am using query SELECT * FROM test; in plpython code. If I do select id,name from test; it breaks. Still need to find a way to tackle it without defining a new type.

Comment: You can create a TYPE instead of a table. https://stackoverflow.com/a/38315231/487992